# tinymce table on textarea. Tab key doesnt move cursor to next cell

Tags: cursor, tinymce, focus, textarea

I am using TinyMCE plugin on textarea. As i insert table with particular rows and columns, it creates the table. But when the cursor is focused on one cell and on pressing TAB, the cursor wont move to the next cell until i start typing and the cursor is then visible.

this issue happens only on IE9 and works fine on FireFox.

Kindly throw some light upon this issue.
Below is my textarea.

```
<textarea id="${docAnnotationAttrId}" name="docAnnotation" title="${attribute.description}"
        rows="22" cols="80" style="width: 100%; height: 360px"
        class="tinymce" readonly=true><c:out value="${attrMap[attrKey].value}"/></textarea>
    <script>
         var options = {'elementName' : '${docAnnotationAttrId}', 'incidentId' : '${document_uniqueReference.incidentId}', 
                 'contextPath' : '${sharedContextPath}','dictionaries':'${webProperties.tinymceDictionaries}'};
         $('#${docAnnotationAttrId}').edit(options);
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, See me code below which i use to solved it.

```
function handleMyTinyCMETabEventOnChromeIE(){
  tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  $('#tabcontrol').blur();
  tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "");
  return false;
}
```

...

```
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1"></textarea>
<a id='tabcontrol' onfocus="javascript: handleMyTinyCMETabEventOnChromeIE()" tabindex='0' href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Hi @Rico Nguyen,
I tried putting your piece of js function in a different script tag but dint work. Could you help me out where exactly should it be added?